# Guardar valor de textview en una variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo el siguiente TextView declarado:

```
TextView billChangeTV[0] = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.billChangeTabCash);
```

Quería saber cómo puedo guardar el valor que aparece aquí en una variable de tipo double.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando tengas el textview puedes hacer textview.getText().toString()

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, he conseguido guardar la variable en una String, pero para pasarlo a double necesito un método?

Comment: El método Double.parseDouble(string) te genera un double a partir de un string siempore que el string se pueda convertir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tendrías que hacer obtener el texto del TextView con `getText()` y luego transformalo a un Double con `Double.parseDouble(String)`

```
TextView billChangeTV[0] = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.billChangeTabCash);
Double respuesta = Double.parseDouble(billChangeTV[0].getText());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, me habéis sido de mucha ayuda.